# Flutter color part of row in DataTable

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout, flutter-datatable

Is it possible to only color a part of a row in a DataTable like 55% of the space?

[image: Example]

I am open to alternatives to the DataTable.

I tried it with DataRow color but that colors the complete row.

Comment: Add some code and what have you tried so far to achieve the results?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution by making a custom DataTable class with two new parameters and some other code changes. Please let me know if someone finds a better solution.

Copy the code from original DataTable and add/replace the following code parts

Here are the relevant code parts:

```
class CustomDataTable extends StatelessWidget {
  CustomDataTable({
    Key? key,
    required this.columns,
    this.sortColumnIndex,
    this.sortAscending = true,
    this.onSelectAll,
    this.decoration,
    this.dataRowColor,
    this.dataRowHeight,
    this.dataTextStyle,
    this.headingRowColor,
    this.headingRowHeight,
    this.headingTextStyle,
    this.horizontalMargin,
    this.columnSpacing,
    this.showCheckboxColumn = true,
    this.showBottomBorder = false,
    this.dividerThickness,
    required this.rows,
    this.checkboxHorizontalMargin,
    this.border,
    this.dataRowPartIndicatorList,
    this.dataRowPartColorGradientList,
  }) : assert(columns.isNotEmpty),
       assert(sortColumnIndex == null || (sortColumnIndex >= 0 && sortColumnIndex < columns.length)),
       assert(!rows.any((DataRow row) => row.cells.length != columns.length)),
       assert(dividerThickness == null || dividerThickness >= 0),
       _onlyTextColumn = _initOnlyTextColumn(columns),
       super(key: key);

  /// List of rows. Indicates how much of the row should be colored.
  /// Values from 1 to 100.
  final List<int?>? dataRowPartIndicatorList;

  /// List of rows. The color is used to color part of the row.
  final List<Color?>? dataRowPartColorGradientList;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    assert(!_debugInteractive || debugCheckHasMaterial(context));

    final ThemeData theme = Theme.of(context);
    final DataTableThemeData dataTableTheme = DataTableTheme.of(context);
    final MaterialStateProperty<Color?>? effectiveHeadingRowColor = headingRowColor
      ?? dataTableTheme.headingRowColor
      ?? theme.dataTableTheme.headingRowColor;
    final MaterialStateProperty<Color?>? effectiveDataRowColor = dataRowColor
      ?? dataTableTheme.dataRowColor
      ?? theme.dataTableTheme.dataRowColor;
    final MaterialStateProperty<Color?> defaultRowColor = MaterialStateProperty.resolveWith(
      (Set<MaterialState> states) {
        if (states.contains(MaterialState.selected)) {
          return theme.colorScheme.primary.withOpacity(0.08);
        }
        return null;
      },
    );
    final bool anyRowSelectable = rows.any((DataRow row) => row.onSelectChanged != null);
    final bool displayCheckboxColumn = showCheckboxColumn && anyRowSelectable;
    final Iterable<DataRow> rowsWithCheckbox = displayCheckboxColumn ?
      rows.where((DataRow row) => row.onSelectChanged != null) : <DataRow>[];
    final Iterable<DataRow> rowsChecked = rowsWithCheckbox.where((DataRow row) => row.selected);
    final bool allChecked = displayCheckboxColumn && rowsChecked.length == rowsWithCheckbox.length;
    final bool anyChecked = displayCheckboxColumn && rowsChecked.isNotEmpty;
    final bool someChecked = anyChecked && !allChecked;
    final double effectiveHorizontalMargin = horizontalMargin
      ?? dataTableTheme.horizontalMargin
      ?? theme.dataTableTheme.horizontalMargin
      ?? _horizontalMargin;
    final double effectiveCheckboxHorizontalMarginStart = checkboxHorizontalMargin
      ?? dataTableTheme.checkboxHorizontalMargin
      ?? theme.dataTableTheme.checkboxHorizontalMargin
      ?? effectiveHorizontalMargin;
    final double effectiveCheckboxHorizontalMarginEnd = checkboxHorizontalMargin
      ?? dataTableTheme.checkboxHorizontalMargin
      ?? theme.dataTableTheme.checkboxHorizontalMargin
      ?? effectiveHorizontalMargin / 2.0;
    final double effectiveColumnSpacing = columnSpacing
      ?? dataTableTheme.columnSpacing
      ?? theme.dataTableTheme.columnSpacing
      ?? _columnSpacing;


    final List<TableColumnWidth> tableColumns = List<TableColumnWidth>.filled(columns.length + (displayCheckboxColumn ? 1 : 0), const _NullTableColumnWidth());
    final List<TableRow> tableRows = List<TableRow>.generate(
      rows.length + 1, // the +1 is for the header row
      (int index) {
        final bool isSelected = index > 0 && rows[index - 1].selected;
        final bool isDisabled = index > 0 && anyRowSelectable && rows[index - 1].onSelectChanged == null;
        final Set<MaterialState> states = <MaterialState>{
          if (isSelected)
            MaterialState.selected,
          if (isDisabled)
            MaterialState.disabled,
        };
        final Color? resolvedDataRowColor = index > 0 ? (rows[index - 1].color ?? effectiveDataRowColor)?.resolve(states) : null;
        final Color? resolvedHeadingRowColor = effectiveHeadingRowColor?.resolve(<MaterialState>{});
        final Color? rowColor = index > 0 ? resolvedDataRowColor : resolvedHeadingRowColor;
        final BorderSide borderSide = Divider.createBorderSide(
          context,
          width: dividerThickness
            ?? dataTableTheme.dividerThickness
            ?? theme.dataTableTheme.dividerThickness
            ?? _dividerThickness,
        );
        final Border? border = showBottomBorder
          ? Border(bottom: borderSide)
          : index == 0 ? null : Border(top: borderSide);
        return TableRow(
          key: index == 0 ? _headingRowKey : rows[index - 1].key,
          decoration: BoxDecoration(
            border: border,
            color: rowColor ?? defaultRowColor.resolve(states),
            gradient: index != 0 && dataRowPartIndicatorList != null && dataRowPartColorGradientList != null ? LinearGradient(
              colors: List.generate(100, (indexList) => indexList < dataRowPartIndicatorList![index - 1]! ? dataRowPartColorGradientList![index - 1]!.withOpacity(0.4) : Colors.transparent),
              begin: Alignment.centerLeft,
              stops: List.generate(100, (indexList) => indexList.toDouble() * 0.01),
            ) : null,
          ),
          children: List<Widget>.filled(tableColumns.length, const _NullWidget()),
        );
      },
    );

    int rowIndex;

    int displayColumnIndex = 0;
    if (displayCheckboxColumn) {
      tableColumns[0] = FixedColumnWidth(effectiveCheckboxHorizontalMarginStart + Checkbox.width + effectiveCheckboxHorizontalMarginEnd);
      tableRows[0].children![0] = _buildCheckbox(
        context: context,
        checked: someChecked ? null : allChecked,
        onRowTap: null,
        onCheckboxChanged: (bool? checked) => _handleSelectAll(checked, someChecked),
        overlayColor: null,
        tristate: true,
      );
      rowIndex = 1;
      for (final DataRow row in rows) {
        tableRows[rowIndex].children![0] = _buildCheckbox(
          context: context,
          checked: row.selected,
          onRowTap: row.onSelectChanged == null ? null : () => row.onSelectChanged?.call(!row.selected),
          onCheckboxChanged: row.onSelectChanged,
          overlayColor: row.color ?? effectiveDataRowColor,
          tristate: false,
        );
        rowIndex += 1;
      }
      displayColumnIndex += 1;
    }

    for (int dataColumnIndex = 0; dataColumnIndex < columns.length; dataColumnIndex += 1) {
      final DataColumn column = columns[dataColumnIndex];

      final double paddingStart;
      if (dataColumnIndex == 0 && displayCheckboxColumn && checkboxHorizontalMargin != null) {
        paddingStart = effectiveHorizontalMargin;
      } else if (dataColumnIndex == 0 && displayCheckboxColumn) {
        paddingStart = effectiveHorizontalMargin / 2.0;
      } else if (dataColumnIndex == 0 && !displayCheckboxColumn) {
        paddingStart = effectiveHorizontalMargin;
      } else {
        paddingStart = effectiveColumnSpacing / 2.0;
      }

      final double paddingEnd;
      if (dataColumnIndex == columns.length - 1) {
        paddingEnd = effectiveHorizontalMargin;
      } else {
        paddingEnd = effectiveColumnSpacing / 2.0;
      }

      final EdgeInsetsDirectional padding = EdgeInsetsDirectional.only(
        start: paddingStart,
        end: paddingEnd,
      );
      if (dataColumnIndex == _onlyTextColumn) {
        tableColumns[displayColumnIndex] = const IntrinsicColumnWidth(flex: 1.0);
      } else {
        tableColumns[displayColumnIndex] = const IntrinsicColumnWidth();
      }
      tableRows[0].children![displayColumnIndex] = _buildHeadingCell(
        context: context,
        padding: padding,
        label: column.label,
        tooltip: column.tooltip,
        numeric: column.numeric,
        onSort: column.onSort != null ? () => column.onSort!(dataColumnIndex, sortColumnIndex != dataColumnIndex || !sortAscending) : null,
        sorted: dataColumnIndex == sortColumnIndex,
        ascending: sortAscending,
        overlayColor: effectiveHeadingRowColor,
      );
      rowIndex = 1;
      for (final DataRow row in rows) {
        final DataCell cell = row.cells[dataColumnIndex];
        tableRows[rowIndex].children![displayColumnIndex] = _buildDataCell(
          context: context,
          padding: padding,
          label: cell.child,
          numeric: column.numeric,
          placeholder: cell.placeholder,
          showEditIcon: cell.showEditIcon,
          onTap: cell.onTap,
          onDoubleTap: cell.onDoubleTap,
          onLongPress: cell.onLongPress,
          onTapCancel: cell.onTapCancel,
          onTapDown: cell.onTapDown,
          onSelectChanged: row.onSelectChanged == null ? null : () => row.onSelectChanged?.call(!row.selected),
          overlayColor: row.color ?? effectiveDataRowColor,
          onRowLongPress: row.onLongPress,
        );
        rowIndex += 1;
      }
      displayColumnIndex += 1;
    }

    return Container(
      decoration: decoration ?? dataTableTheme.decoration ?? theme.dataTableTheme.decoration,
      child: Material(
        type: MaterialType.transparency,
        child: Table(
          columnWidths: tableColumns.asMap(),
          children: tableRows,
          border: border,
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```